# Why solution generate by CMake not output the same files size than Visual

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I've generate a solution for Visual Studio with CMake. It compile fines like the original solution. But when i look at my output folder, the files are not the same size as those generated by the initial solution.

**Example :**

DLL generate by initial solution : 
core.dll - 767ko

The same DLL generate by the solution of CMake : 
core.dll - 669Ko

And the same thing appears for a .lib :
zlib.lib - 305 Ko (for the initial solution)
zlib.lib - 242 Ko (for the CMake solution)

But I use Visual Studio 2013 for two... And the types are the same : Debug / Win32. I verify all the Flags multiple time, but anyway it still generate different size files.

**EDIT :** I add my CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Configuration of Types
MESSAGE("Generated with config types: ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}")
SET(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
#SET(CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR ${BUILD_PATH})

#Configuration of zlib.lib
PROJECT(zlib C)
# Path of Release
SET(LIB_RELEASE_PATH "../build/cmake_x64")
SET( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${LIB_RELEASE_PATH}/lib/" )
SET( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${LIB_RELEASE_PATH}/lib/" )
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${LIB_RELEASE_PATH}/lib/" )
# Path of Debug
SET(LIB_DEBUG_PATH "../build/cmake_x64d")
SET( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${LIB_DEBUG_PATH}/lib/" )
SET( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${LIB_DEBUG_PATH}/lib/" )
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${LIB_DEBUG_PATH}/lib/" )
#Flags
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W3 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D_UNICODE")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} /GL /Oi /Gy /GR- /Gm-")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} /Gm /Ob0- /GR- /Gm")
# Files of librairy
ADD_LIBRARY(

    zlib

    STATIC

    ../.c
    and
    ../.h

)

#Configuration of core.dll
project(core CXX)
# Path of Release
SET(BIN_RELEASE_PATH "../build/cmake_x64")
SET( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_RELEASE_PATH}/bin/" )
SET( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_RELEASE_PATH}/bin/" )
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${BIN_RELEASE_PATH}/bin/" )
# Path of Debug
SET(BIN_DEBUG_PATH "../build/cmake_x64d")
SET( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DEBUG_PATH}/bin/" )
SET( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DEBUG_PATH}/bin/" )
SET( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${BIN_DEBUG_PATH}/bin/" )
# Flags
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4 /D_UNICODE /D_USRDLL /DCORE_EXPORTS /DUNICODE")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Zi /GL /Oi /Gy /DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO /GR- /Gm-")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /Gm /GR-")

# Files of librairy
add_library(

        core

        SHARED

    ../.h
    and
    ../.cpp

)

target_link_libraries(core zlib)
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET core APPEND PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS /DEBUG)
#END OF FILE
```

And here is my Ouput from Command Line :

```
Generated with config types:
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CMak
eDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:106 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
  is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CMak
eFindBinUtils.cmake:33 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
  is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler
.cmake:162 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/mea/Documents/developpement/Repos/
corealpi2/cmake/build
```

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you compare the settings (compiler, linker, ...) of the CMake-generated solution and the one you created yourself?

Comment: Yes i compare it and this is the same... i don't understand why it's not the same size. And I verify all the properties project. I make a link libraries in my CMakeLists file to put zlib in references in visual, maybe it's come from this and it is not the thing i have to do ?

Comment: @JohannesS. I add my CMakeLists.txt